# What Can I Do To Make My Game Harder For The Party's Alchemist?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

OK, so one of my players was playing a Gunslinger. Her character had to part ways with some of the party in a very cool scene. The party's ninja went with her and their True Neutral Wizard straight up abandoned the rest of the group.

In the interest of keeping the party balance, the player who was playing a gunslinger decided to make a goblin alchemist (touch based ranged attacks). However, some of the class features, such as splash damage and the fly speed, made some of the encounters I had planned suddenly seem very simple for the party.

What should I make the party face in the interest of keeping the game difficult? Many of the encounters I had planned involved creatures with high AC but poor Touch AC. That would not be such a problem if the character didn't have a fly speed and could easily go out of the enemy's attack range.

I had also planned encounters against many weak creatures, something that now seems pointless because of the splash damage. My players asked for the game to be challenging, but not impossible, with character deaths being somewhat frequent. I have managed to maintain the expected level of challenge until now.

Comment: This is the first time I have used this site. If I am ignoring any rules, I would be very pleased if you told me so. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi Solar, and welcome to the site! I can tell you that your question's drawing votes-to-hold for being too broad. Some details you could [edit] in to scope the question would be what encounters you had planned which turned out easy (and how), and what conversations you and the players have had about what challenges (type and difficulty) they want to face. When you get a minute take the [tour] and browse through some other [pathfinder encounter-building questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder+encounter-design?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Happy gaming!

Comment: I can give you a partial answer, but it would help if you can describe in more detail what the Alchemist is doing that's causing you so much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most caster-types, Alchemists have to play the resource-management game: their supply of bombs, extracts, and mutagens are limited per-day, and they have to choose when to use them and when to use less awesome means of achieving their goals (eg., a bow or a sword instead of a bomb).

Time pressure is their greatest foe: having a good in-game reason to avoid the "15-minute adventuring day" (ie., rest after virtually every encounter) will force them to be more judicious in when to bring the big guns and when to hold them in reserve. Alongside that, I've found that having a few small encounters (things that last 2-3 rounds and *aren't hard*, but feel natural for the locale - a small group with a CR of [APL](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#Step-1-Determine-APL)-2, or even [APL](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#Step-1-Determine-APL)-3 if they have some terrain advantages, maybe a scout, etc.) help the session keep moving while the casters manage their resources (YMMV, of course).

You called out splash damage and flight as two particular abilities that you foresee being problematic. For the former, a single foe (or a small number that keep their distance from each other) will significantly reduce the utility of splash damage; so, too, will foes that rush up and stand next to one or two party members. Flight can be mitigated by low ceilings or high winds. And, remember that [Flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly/) is a skill; don't let the player get away with things that the skill doesn't allow (or, doesn't allow at their skill level).

All of that said, I would encourage you not to spend too much time specifically figuring out how to counter any one PC, at least until they prove to be a problem. Let the character be awesome, and let the player have fun with that.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I am now changing some of the encounters as well as making more of them being in the same day. I will also make sure to put more combats with foes that are quick to aproach others. Again, thank you for the time and the care.

Answer (score 1):

In general, alchemists are very resource-dependent - they have a limited number of bombs, extracts, and mutagens per day that they have to manage. Longer days with more encounters are hard on them because they have to be more judicious in using those resources.

Because alchemists gain a lot of their power from extracts, they do very well when encounters are clustered together and buffs can carry over from one fight to the next. Conversely, they have a harder time in fights that are unexpected, where they have to choose between drinking their mutagen in the first round or just attacking.

Because bombs deal energy damage, energy resistance can really cut into their effectiveness. Since bomb specialists also tend to take discoveries that allow them to inflict conditions, monsters that are immune to those conditions will also be tougher for them.